# connection.createStatement in Spring-managed datasource never return

Tags: mysql, spring, jersey, tomcat7, jndi

This is very strange in my RESTful WS development. I am using Tomcat 7 with Jersey 1.8, Spring 2.5 and MySQL database.

I defined two data sources like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MAINDB" />
  <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="orderDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" scope="singleton">
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/ORDERS" />
  <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
</bean>
```

and inject one data source into the servlet context like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
  <property name="attributes">
    <map>
      <entry key="orderData">
        <ref bean="orderDataSource" />
      </entry>
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

and this code:

```
orderDataSource = (DataSource) sc.getServletContext().getAttribute("orderData");
Order ord = new Order();
Statement stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = orderDataSource.getConnection().createStatement();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(OrdersResource.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

gets executed 6 or 7 times flawlessly and from the 8th request, it gets stall at createStatement() line and never return or throw any exception!

However, all other resources API from MAINDB still works very well.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Comment: Try to close the connection when you're done. connection.close();

Comment: then will the connection be available back when I call getConnection()?

Comment: Yes. Or you can use the JdbcTemplate as Stéphane Nicoll said(then it will happen automatically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you bothering with such code yourself? If you are using Spring already, use the [`JdbcTemplate`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) instead. It can be initialized with your `DataSource` and will manage all that for you.

You are requiring a connection from the pool but you never closes it (same for the statement actually). Using `JdbcTemplate` prevents you from having those issues in the first place.

Something like

```
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
jdbcTemplate.execute(...)
```

See [the javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've got to know how to use jdbcTemplate. However when I come to execute an INSERT and want to have the generated key return, the procedure is quite complex right? using PreparedStatementCreator

Comment: I don't see why it could be any complex that the code you have put in your description. You can use a `StatementCallback` and get access to the statement that will be closed automatically for you (as well as the related connection). So if you use `execute(StatementCallback)` you get exactly the same thing.